# How do I merge two workbooks when one has intentionally duplicate data?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I started using pandas very recently. In both workbooks I have a column called CODE. The first work book has a shorter column of unique codes, like 1009. In the second workbook, the list is longer and 1009 can appear many times. I want all of the info from a row in the smaller workbook to copied and appended onto every row that has the same code in the second workbook.

**Workbook 1**

```
CODE x y

1009 1 3

1112 3 2
```

**Workbook 2**

```
CODE n

1009 bob

1009 john

1112 mark

1112 dan

1112 finn
```

**Final Workbook**

```
CODE n x y

1009 bob 1 3

1009 john 1 3

1112 mark 3 2

1112 dan 3 2

1112 finn 3 2
```

**My attempt:**

```py
import pandas as pd
#Opening workbook
wb1 = pd.read_excel('one.xlsx')    #short list
wb2 = pd.read_excel('two.xlsx')    #looooong list

result = pd.merge(wb1, wb2, on=['CODE'])
result.to_excel('merged.xlsx')
```

Comment: Try `wb1.merge(wb2, on=['CODE'], how='left')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for? Make sure to know how `merge` works and its hyperparameters (mostly `on` and `how`).

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'CODE':[1009,1112],'x':[1,3],'y':[3,2]}

b = {'CODE':[1009,1009,1112,1112,1112],'n':['bob','john','mark','dan','finn']}
dfa = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
c = dfb.merge(dfa, on='CODE', how='left')
print(c)
```

This output gets me the requested dataframe:

```
   CODE     n  x  y
0  1009   bob  1  3
1  1009  john  1  3
2  1112  mark  3  2
3  1112   dan  3  2
4  1112  finn  3  2
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time understanding the documentation for merge.

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions below.